# Show a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource in a PictureBox in WindowsForm in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, picturebox

I want to draw a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource in a picture Box.
in WPF application i do it with this :

```
image1.Source =BitmapSource.Create(....................);
```

but now I have a form. I import PresentationCore.dll in my form to have BitmapSource;
but now how I can draw or show it On a PictureBox like this ? :

```
pictureBox1.Image=BitmapSource.Create(.....................);
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why do you want/need to use wpf-specific things?

look at this snippet
[How to convert BitmapSource to Bitmap](http://snipplr.com/view/63090/)

```
Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        bitmap = new Bitmap(outStream);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Usage:

```
pictureBox1.Image = BitmapFromSource(yourBitmapSource);
```

If you want to open an image file...:

```
pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\image.jpg");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was solved with your solution.Thanks

Comment: This produces error for me: "Error CS7069 Reference to type 'DispatcherObject' claims it is defined in 'WindowsBase', but it could not be found" at enc.Save. Also could you include the full imports? It's kinda guesswork otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK for you?

```
ImageSource imgSourceFromBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Comment: This code leaks a HBITMAP handle, you have to call `DeleteObject()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1dz311e4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This method has better performance (twice faster) and need lower memory as it doesn't copy data to `MemoryStream`:

```
Bitmap GetBitmapFromSource(BitmapSource source) //, bool alphaTransparency
{
    //convert image pixel format:
    var bs32 = new FormatConvertedBitmap(); //inherits from BitmapSource
    bs32.BeginInit();
    bs32.Source = source;
    bs32.DestinationFormat = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32;
    bs32.EndInit();
    //source = bs32;

    //now convert it to Bitmap:
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bs32.PixelWidth, bs32.PixelHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
    bs32.CopyPixels(System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, data.Scan0, data.Height * data.Stride, data.Stride);
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    return bmp;
}
```